# Numerical/integration methods within dynamic SABR

Tags: stochastic-volatility, sabr

I have a question regarding volatility estimates in the dynamic SABR model. It is well known that the original Hagan et al. (2002) approximation formula for the SABR model does not work good for extreme strikes/maturities. For the dynamic SABR model, similar approximations are available with the advantage that they are fast, but they have the same flaws as the original approximations from Hagan et al. (2002).

For the constant parameter SABR model, more accurate approximations are available via integration, see for example Antonov et al (2013), called 'SABR spreads its wings'. However, as of yet I have not come across any integration methods for the dynamic SABR model. I do suspect that the currently available integration methods for the constant parameter SABR model can easily be used in the dynamic SABR model, but I'm not 100% sure.

For example, the following quote is from Antonov et al (2013), where approximations are derived for the constant parameter SABR model:

> The high accuracy of our approximation is very important for dynamic  SABR  models,  where  analytic  approximation  used  in  calibration should provide results close to those used in pricing, for  example,  SABR  Libor  market  models,  as  in  Mercurio  &  Morini (2009) and Rebonato, McKay & White (2009).

This seems to indicate that their method can be used within the dynamic framework as well. I hope someone can elaborate, thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by _dynamic_ SABR model? Do you mean the SABR model with time-dependent (but deterministic) model parameters?